# Can't figure out how to get a pattern enclosed in HTML tag using a Regex

Tags: regex

I just started learning about Regexes and can't figure out how to lift `Gizmo` from the HTML tag

```
<meta content="Gizmo" property="og:title" />
```

I'm stuck at the `(?<Name>meta content=)`, which is basically nothing, but I don't know what to do from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well known you shouldn't use regex to parse html (actually, it's been said millon times), **you should use a html parser** instead.

On the other hand, if you want to use regex for this... you are pretty close, you have to use:

```
(?<Name>meta content=".*?")
```

Btw, if you want to grab the word `Gizmo` you have to use capturing groups also withing your group Name

```
(?<Name>meta content="(.*?)")
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH9fH5/1)**

On the other hand, if you don't care about capturing `meta content` and you just want to capture the content within content, you can use use:

```
content="(?<Name>.*?)"
```

**[Working demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/oH9fH5/2)**

Comment: Thanks! But it looks like it also extracts `meta content="` and `"` along with Gizmo?

Comment: @exlo look at the demo link, you can find the group index 2 having gizmo

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new so I'm a little confused. If `Name Gizmo` is what I want, let's say using a simple demo like http://rubular.com/, then the match is `meta content="Colony Cafe"`. Is it possible to skip `"meta content="` and `"` all together?

And it's for an assignment so I have to use regexes unfortunately

Comment: Got it! Thank you. But if I'm looking at a source where there are multiple meta content tags, and the identifier is `"og:title"`, would I make it `content="(?<Name>.*?)" property="og:title"` ? I tried it, and it's returning no matches

Comment: @exlo Yes, it will work only if `og:title` comes after content, otherwise it won't work.